# PHP: Decrypt string received from Kotlin encryption

Tags: php, kotlin, encryption, openssl, aes

I encrypted a string in Kotlin using the following code

```
private fun encrypt(context: Context, strToEncrypt: String, encryptKey : String): ByteArray {
        
        val plainText = strToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
        val key = generateKey(encryptKey)
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_256/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText)
        return cipherText
    }

    private fun generateKey(password: String): SecretKeySpec {

        val digest: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        val bytes = password.toByteArray()
        digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
        val key = digest.digest()
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        return secretKeySpec
    }
```

and I use it like this:

```
encrypt(requireContext(), "test_string", "password")
```

Now I need to decrypt the generated string in PHP (receiving string via GET). I have something like this:

```
function decryptString($encryptedString, $cipher, $key, $initVector) {

    // decrypt and return string
    return openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, $cipher, $key, 0, $initVector);
}

if (isset($_GET["plain_text"])) {
    
    // define cipher algorithm
    $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";

    // generate initialization vector
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);

    echo decryptString($_GET["plain_text"], $cipher, "password", $iv);
}
```

But the result is empty. I guess this is because in PHP I can use a string as key for decription (the `$key` parameter in the `openssl_decrypt()` procedure) defined by me, while in Kotlin (damned Android is always overly complicated for no reason), you are forced to use a `SecretKeySpec` parameter as key, so I cannot pass an hardcoded string as key.

I'm not an encryption expert, so forgive me for the dumb question.

Comment: You're hashing the password in Kotlin to derive the key, but not in PHP, so how could it work?

Comment: And you're not using the same IV in Kotlin and PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin code automatically generates a random IV, which you must fetch and pass together with the ciphertext. It is common to concatenate both, e.g. iv|ciphertext. You can use Base64 to generate a string from the byte array:

```kotlin
private fun encrypt(strToEncrypt: String, encryptKey : String): String {
    val plainText = strToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    val key = generateKey(encryptKey)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_256/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    val cipherText = cipher.iv + cipher.doFinal(plainText) // get IV and concatenate with ciphertext
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText)  // Base64 encode data
}
```

On the PHP side, the IV must be stripped off from the ciphertext. In addition, the key must be derived with SHA256 as in the Kotlin code (by the way, it is better to use PBKDF2 or more modern KDFs):

```php
$ivCt = base64_decode('p5ONPQVga2KWX5nM1mHI04uXRYCqFXUTYgsiIurQdfF+qidI5YOOjhn2s9g/DYuq'); // sample data from Kotlin code
$iv = substr($ivCt, 0, 16); // strip IV off
$ct = substr($ivCt, 16);
$pwd = 'your password';
$key = hash('sha256', $pwd, true); // derive key with SHA256
$dt = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); // disable default Base64 with OPENSSL_RAW_DATA 
print($dt . PHP_EOL); // Take me to your leader
```

Comment: Thank you! simple and well explained solution for me (a noob in cryptography). It works perfectly

Comment: Just wanted to specify that, according to php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#55901 the encrypted value must be smaller than the key (due to the maths used to do the actual encryption).

Comment: @user2959923 - No, you are confusing `openssl_encrypt()` and `openssl_public_encrypt()`. Your question is about AES (**symmetric** encryption), for which `openssl_encrypt()` is required and for which there is no limitation on the length of the plaintext. In contrast, `openssl_public_encrypt()` refers to **asymmetric** encryption (with RSA), where only small amounts of data can indeed be encrypted (depending on the key size and padding chosen).